# Lists become pd.Series, the again lists with one dimension more

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have another problem with pandas, I will never make mine this library.

First, this is - I think - how `zip()` is supposed to work with lists:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = [1,2]
b = [3,4]
print(type(a))
print(type(b))

vv = zip([1,2], [3,4])
for i, v in enumerate(vv):
    print(f"{i}: {v}")
```

with output:

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
0: (1, 3)
1: (2, 4)
```

Problem. I create a dataframe, with list elements (in the actual code the lists come from grouping ops and I cannot change them, basically they contain all the values in a dataframe grouped by a column).

```
# create dataframe
values = [{'x': list( (1, 2, 3) ), 'y': list( (4, 5, 6))}]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(values)
print(df)

           x          y
0  [1, 2, 3]  [4, 5, 6]
```

However, the lists are now `pd.Series`:

```
print(type(df["x"]))


<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

If I do this:

```
col1 = df["x"].tolist()
col2 = df["y"].tolist()

print(f"col1 is of type {type(col1)}, with length {len(col1)}, first el is {col1[0]} of type {type(col1[0])}")

col1 is of type <class 'list'>, width length 1, first el is [1, 2, 3] of type <class 'list'>
```

Basically, the `tolist()` returned a list of list (why?):

Indeed:

```
print("ZIP AND ITER")
vv = zip(col1, col2)
for v in zip(col1, col2):
    print(v)

ZIP AND ITER
([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
```

I neeed only to compute this:

```
# this fails because x (y) is a list
# df['s'] = [np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2) for x, y in zip(df["x"], df["y"])]
```

I could add `df["x"][0]` that seems not very elegant.

Question:
How am I supposed to compute `sqrt(x^2 + y^2)` when `x` and `y` are in two columns `df["x"]` and `df["y"]`

Comment: `df.dtypes` should show that both columns are `object` dtype.  The columns, Series, contain lists, not numbers.  So yes, `tolist` should return a list of lists.  That would be more obvious if created the frame with more than one row.  What's in-elegante about `df['x'][0]`?  That's what you need to do to recover the list from the list.

Comment: If you have lists of lists you have  to iterate both levels to do math on individual numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should calculate `df['s']`

```
df['s'] = df.apply(lambda row: [np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2) for x, y in zip(row["x"], row["y"])], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, the tolist() returned a list of list (why?):

Because your dataframe has only 1 row, with two columns and both columns contain a `list` for its value. So, returning that column as a `list` of its values, it would return a `list` with 1 element (the list that is the value).

I think you wanted to create a dataframe like this:

```
values = {'x': list( (1, 2, 3) ), 'y': list( (4, 5, 6))}

   x  y
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

Comment: No, the dataframe is correct and the actual dataframe has more than one row. The value at [index, x] is a list.

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood the question then.

Answer (score 0):

```
values = [{'x': list( (1, 2, 3) ), 'y': list( (4, 5, 6))}]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(values)
```

print(df) # yields

```
           x          y
 0  [1, 2, 3]  [4, 5, 6]
```

An elegant solution to computing sqrt(x^2 + y^2) can be done by converting the dataframe as following:

```
new_df = df.iloc[0,:].apply(pd.Series).T.reset_index(drop=True)
```

This yields the follwoing output

```
    x   y
0   1   4
1   2   5
2   3   6
```

Now compute the sqrt(x^2 + y^2)

```
np.sqrt(new_df['x']**2 + new_df['y']**2)
```

This yields :

```
0    4.123106
1    5.385165
2    6.708204
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Elegant, but incredibly complex: I couldn't understand all of it.